# express debug module not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm on **Windows** trying to use the **debug module** https://www.npmjs.org/package/debug

I installed express-generator

```
var debug = require('debug')('MyApp');
debug('log'); // I don't see this on console
```

I tried to debug the variable

```
console.log(debug); // I get function disabled() {}
```

How to enable it? shouldn't be enabled by default?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Output from debug functions created by the `debug` module are only displayed when you set the appropriate environment variable when starting your script. That is what lets you selectively enable debug output so that it's not an all or nothing method of displaying debug information. This is similar to how node.js core works for showing internal debug information on the console.

So in your example you would need to execute this at your shell prompt: `DEBUG=MyApp node foo.js`, where `foo.js` is your script containing `var debug = require('debug')('MyApp');`.

For Windows you'd need to do `set DEBUG=MyApp` on the command line, followed by `node foo.js`.

Comment: I execute using 'npm start', if I do it your way it doesn't work, it will tell me "DEBUG" is not recognized. There must be a way to enable debugger for all files. no?

Comment: You could try exporting the variable first (`export DEBUG=MyApp`) and then running `npm start`, it should have the same effect.

Comment: Windows users: see @NizarBlond's translation of this into a Windows command prompt expression. `export` is the OSX/bash shell version of the Windows `set` command to set environment variables.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work if you are using `nodemon`, but this did work when switching quickly to test your solution

Comment: @mtpultz Since nodemon also uses the `debug` module, it could be that `debug` is deleting `process.env.DEBUG` once it is loaded by nodemon, meaning it won't get passed on to child processes spawned by nodemon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)  I just got it working, but had to add `--inspect` or if legacy `--debug`.  Now I'm trying to find a way to set it without using the command line argument so I don't have to keep shutting down docker to debug different modules as I work.  Just tried `process.env.DEBUG` in my `app.js`, but that didn't work so onto Googling.

Comment: Okay and figured this out too.  I was loading my environment variables from `dotenv` after debug had already imported so it didn't see any of them.

Comment: upvoted! so when you call debug('test') does this statement get executed when you dont set the environment variable?

Comment: If I do
```import debug from 'debug';





debug('brp-node')```
It doesn't work.. can someone help?

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to set it in your js code,

**myapp-debug.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.env['DEBUG'] = 'myapp:server';
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');

// ...
```

- I find it useful when there's a single shebanged executable file (on windows you'l need to set `node` to open `.js` files)

Answer (score 4):

I was also faces the same issue. Finally i get the solution that
In windows

> set DEBUG=* & node index.js

above command has to work. But in my this is not working on VS code terminal. But if is you write this command in scripts section of your package.json then it will work.

> "start": "set DEBUG=app & node app.js"

Now you just need to write

> npm start

on terminal and there you go

Answer (score 3):

On windows set DEBUG=* or your configured name for debug e.g. myApp. In all js files whenever I want debug I configured just like following statement.

```
var debug = require('debug')('MyApp');
```

require('debug')**('MyApp')**;  //This is very imp. You should configured some name for debug

while executing on windows

```
D:>set DEBUG=MyApp

D:>node <your app file>.js 

D:> node foo.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not set environment variables the way Linux and others do.

The solution is:

```
set DEBUG=my-application
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this issue out as well and it seems to me (at least on my Windows 10 machine) that the way to do this (at least from a non-linux command line; I am using the WebStorm build-in command line) is to include the '&' operator. So write something like this:

```
set DEBUG=my-app & node index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `process.env.DEBUG` has been set before you create the debug logger.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you cannot run the express debug in terminal using

> set DEBUG=express:* & node index.js

on Windows, put

> "this": "set DEBUG=express:* & node --experimental-json-modules index.js"

inside "scripts" in package.json, then type

> npm run this

in terminal. Thanks for reading!